# Fulfill all Conditional condition in WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to retrieve data with multiple condition, where each condition will contain certain keywords in certain fields.

The table structure is as below:
sid nid  cid  data
50   7    5   ee
50   7     6   aa
50   7     8   ff
51   7     5     ee
51   7     6    ee
52   7     8     ff

I would like to retrieve the sid which fulfill these two conditions:
when (cid=5 and data LIKE '%ee%')
when (cid=8 and data LIKE '%ff%')

The sid retrieved should be only 50, not 50, 51 and 52.

It doesn't get the correct result when I write my sql like below:

```
SELECT * FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE
  (cid=5 AND data LIKE '%ee%') AND (cid=8 AND data LIKE '%ff%')
```

So I changed to

```
SELECT * FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE 
CASE `cid`  
WHEN '5' THEN `data` LIKE '%ee%'  
WHEN '8' THEN `data` LIKE '%ff%' 
END
```

But this is not giving correct result too.

Is there any method to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0):

How about counting the number of `SID` and that it should match the number of your conditions?

```
SELECT  sid
FROM    webform_submitted_data
WHERE   (cid=5 AND data LIKE '%ee%')        -- first condition
        OR (cid=8 AND data LIKE '%ff%') -- second condition
GROUP   BY  sid
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2                        -- number of conditions
```

Comment: The sql return no result... Is it because of there is no row contains both cid=5 and cid=8 in same row?

Comment: It works!!! If I'm adding 4 condition, does that mean I have to write the code as HAVING COUNT(*)=4 ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried an OR?

```
SELECT * FROM webform_submitted_data WHERE
  (cid=5 AND data LIKE '%ee%') OR (cid=8 AND data LIKE '%ff%')
```

Comment: I tried it, but it returns 50, 51 and 52, which I actually want the  intersect value 50 only

Answer (score 0):

Here we are getting rows based on first condition and then using exists to see that second case is also matched

```
SELECT T1.* FROM
(SELECT * FROM webform_submitted_data
WHERE 
CASE `cid`  
WHEN '5' THEN `data` LIKE '%ee%' 
END 
)T1
WHERE EXISTS 
(

SELECT 1 FROM webform_submitted_data w
WHERE 
CASE `cid`  
WHEN '8' THEN `data` LIKE '%ff%'
END 
AND w.sid = T1.sid
)
```